How do we assign the 802.1Q Trunks for Interface?
I am new to networking and studying for the Cisco certification exam, and I don't understand how we assign the 802.1Q Trunks for Interface
example Interface S1 F0/1.
How is this done?

Details and specific questions would be helpful. Have search results for Interface S1 F0/1 been reviewed? Such as result 3.4.6 Packet Tracer – Configure VLANs and Trunking – Physical Mode Answers or Cisco Network Acadamy's PDF Packet Tracer - Configure VLANs and Trunking - Physical Mode?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
